# BizTalk pipeline custom component disassemble with no document schema

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013, biztalk-pipelines

I am going to parse and format the flat file input based on the business logic stored in SQL server database tables. I don’t have a document schema for the input. I wrote a  C#  custom component class for the disassemble. When I use the custom component in Disassemble stage in receive pipeline, I am getting document schema not found error.

Did anyone come across with same situation and handled it differently? .

Comment: Any reason you aren't using a Flat File schema to dissasemble the file?  And then have whatever logic in SQL execute later?     Also what is your disassembler emiting as a message?  A XML document.  Do you have a schema in BizTalk for that?

Comment: We have many different message types/formats. Most of them are complex and dynamic. So Flat file schema doesn’t help. At disassemble stage, the message body contains the actual data. No, I don’t have a schema in BizTalk for that. Thanks.

Comment: What exactly u r trying to do in disassemble stage. r u converting flat file to xml or using xmlrecive pipeline component. It would be good to post the exact error message u r getting. Tell us more about u intent

Comment: The question is why can't you use the built-in Flat File Disassembler?  Having many different input formats isn't at all unusual.  Unless you have the very, very unlikely situation of an unsupportable flat file, you're just making things harder on yourself by using custom code.

Comment: Can you explain with more detail what are you doing on your component?

Comment: We have many different  complex  flat file messages such as array of structure within structures and record length varies. Those messages has to be reformatted based on the destinations. So I am  using the custom component, trying to disassemble and reformat the message based on the business rules received from the SQL server. If I don't use a document schema, disassemble gives An exception of type 'Microsoft.BizTalk.Component.FFDasmException' occurred in Microsoft.BizTalk.Pipeline.Components.dll but was not handled in user code  Additional information: Document schema must be set. Thanks.

Comment: In custom component disassemble stage I am reading the first 4 bytes from the input, based on the message type I am setting up value in property schema and I using it to filter in sent port for different destinations. If this part works fine, I am going to read SQL server table and reformat the message in disassemble stage. Thanks.

Comment: The question is still why can't you use the Flat File Disassembler?  That's what it's for.  Trying to parse in C# is making this much harder than it needs to be.

Comment: Here is a simple sample data with one record, it is delimited with pipe. Number of occurrences of Part number and part detail varies based on total parts count. How do we disassemble with Flat File Disassembler?

Cust number|Cust Name|Cust Address|Total Parts Count | Part number | Part detail| Part number | Part detail | Shipment Date | Order number

--thanks.

Answer (score 0):

BizTalk routes messages using the 'MessageType' property (The namespace + the root node name of the XML in the message) in the context portion of the message. You don't have that with your design so it doesn't know what to do with it.

You can:

- handle each type of flat file separately by parsing and assigning a unique message type
- distill the content into one type of message
- wrap the content of the file in an 'envelope'

You'll need to create a schema for any of those choices.

Namespaces and routing are a spiffy way to handle changes to file structure. If you include the version of the file in the namespace BizTalk can route the message to the code that handles that kind of message for you. You can continue to handle old style messages as well as new formats. We handle pilot programs that way.